# Finding a two-dimensional chain

Tags: real-analysis, integration, differential-forms

Let $$T=\{(x,y,z,w,)\in R^4:x^2+y^2=z^2+w^2=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\}$$ and $$\omega=dx\land dy + dz\land dw$$ in $\mathbb R^4$. How do I find a two-dimensional chain $C$ where $T$ is its trace? And how can I calculate $\int_C \omega$?

I missed some lectures on this topic because I was preparing for another exam, some help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: HINT: Think about $x^2+y^2=r^2$ in the $xy$-plane. How do you parametrize that? Similarly for $z^2+w^2=r^2$ in the $zw$-plane. (Obviously, use different letters for your parameters.)

Comment: @TedShifrin I guess $r^2(\cos^2\alpha +\sin^2\alpha)$. Similarly for the other term (maybe using $\beta$ then). And then? :D

Comment: So in this case, $r^2=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$

Comment: @UserUser: Computing the integral is not that hard, but what do you mean by "the trace of a chain"? It is the first time that I encounter this terminology. (Notice that $T$ is a torus embedded in $\Bbb R ^4$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computing the integral is easy. Pick the following natural parametrization of $T$:

$$(x, y, z, w) = \frac 1 {\sqrt[4] 2}(\cos s, \sin s, \cos t, \sin t) $$

with $s,t \in [0, 2 \pi)$.

Notice that

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt[4] 2 \omega &= \Bbb d (\cos s) \wedge \Bbb d (\sin s) + \Bbb d (\cos t) \wedge \Bbb d (\sin t) \\
&= (- \sin s \ \Bbb d s) \wedge (\cos s \ \Bbb d s) + (- \sin t \ \Bbb d t) \wedge (\cos t \ \Bbb d t) \\
&= (-\sin s \cos s) \ (\Bbb d s \wedge \Bbb d s) + (-\sin t \cos t) \ (\Bbb d t \wedge \Bbb d t) \\
&= 0
\end{align}$$

so that $\omega = 0$ (because $\Bbb d s \wedge \Bbb d s = 0$ and $\Bbb d t \wedge \Bbb d t = 0$ and the value of a form in a point is independent of the coordinates chosen around that point), hence its integral is also $0$ (notice that you don't have to "integrate" anything, that's the whole idea of the problem: it looks like a problem about integration, but it turns out to be something else - much simpler, in fact).

In fact, this was to be expected: notice that $T = \{(z, z') \in \Bbb C \times \Bbb C \mid |z| = |z'| = 1\}$, so that $T = S^1 \times S^1$ where $S^1 = \{z \in \Bbb C \mid |z| = 1\}$ (the unit circle in the complex plane). The $\Bbb d x \wedge \Bbb d y$ part, being independent of $u$ and $v$, lives on the first factor $S^1$ of $T$. Since $S^1$ is a curve (so it has dimension $1$) and $\Bbb d x \wedge \Bbb d y$ is a $2$-form, and $2$-forms vanish on $1$-dimensional objects, it is clear now that $\omega = 0$, in spite of the fact that it "looks non-zero".